# How to paginate once number of pages has been scraped? (Scrapy)

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination, scrapy

I'm trying to paginate through a review site that doesn't have hyperlinked pagination buttons. I've written logic to paginate and hardcoded the number of pages for each link. However, I'm wondering if it's possible to use information that I scrape as the number of pages for a given link in `start_requests`.

Spider code here (with 2 links to paginate through):

```
class TareviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tareviews'
    allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.com']
    # start_urls = []

    def start_requests(self):
        for page in range(0,395,5):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60795-d102542-Reviews-or{}-Courtyard_Philadelphia_Airport-Philadelphia_Pennsylvania.html'.format(page))
        for page in range(0,1645,5):
            yield self.make_requests_from_url('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60795-d122332-Reviews-or{}-The_Ritz_Carlton_Philadelphia-Philadelphia_Pennsylvania.html'.format(page))

    def parse(self, response):
        for idx,review in enumerate(response.css('div.review-container')):
            item = {
                'num_reviews': response.css('span.reviews_header_count::text')[0].re(r'\d{0,3}\,?\d{1,3}'),
                'hotel_name': response.css('h1.heading_title::text').extract_first(),
                'review_title': review.css('span.noQuotes::text').extract_first(),
                'review_body': review.css('p.partial_entry::text').extract_first(),
                'review_date': review.xpath('//*[@class="ratingDate relativeDate"]/@title')[idx].extract(),
                'num_reviews_reviewer': review.css('span.badgetext::text').extract_first(),
                'reviewer_name': review.css('span.scrname::text').extract(),
                'bubble_rating': review.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'reviewItemInline')]//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating')]/@class")[idx].re(r'(?<=ui_bubble_rating bubble_).+?(?=0)')
            }
            yield item
```

`'num_reviews'` is the value for the number of the last page for each link. In the `for loop` in `start_requests` it is `395` and `1645`.

Is this possible? I'd like to avoid a headless browser if possible. Thanks!

Comment: in `parse()` you can use `yield Request()` with new url to add it to list.

Comment: The parse, `num_reviews` in this case, returns the number of the last page.  I don't think `yield Request()` would work in this context b.c a loop is needed to execute the pagination once the total number of pages is known.

Comment: if you know number of pages then you can use `yield Request( url=...)` in loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made this code

I use normal url - without `-or{}` - to get page and find number of reviews.
Next I add `-or{}` to url - it can be in any place - to generate urls to pages with reviews.
And then I use `for` loop and `Request()` to get pages with reviews.
Reviews are parsed by different method - `parse_reviews()`

In code I use `scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess()` to run it without full project,
so everyone can easily run and test it.

It saves data in `output.csv`

```
import scrapy

class TareviewsSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'tareviews'
    allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.com']

    start_urls = [ # without `-or{}`
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60795-d102542-Reviews-Courtyard_Philadelphia_Airport-Philadelphia_Pennsylvania.html',
        'https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60795-d122332-Reviews-The_Ritz_Carlton_Philadelphia-Philadelphia_Pennsylvania.html',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        # get number of reviews
        num_reviews = response.css('span.reviews_header_count::text').extract_first()
        num_reviews = num_reviews[1:-1] # remove `( )`
        num_reviews = num_reviews.replace(',', '') # remove `,`
        num_reviews = int(num_reviews) # convert to integer
        print('num_reviews:', num_reviews, type(num_reviews))

        # create template to generate urls to pages with reviews
        url = response.url.replace('.html', '-or{}.html')
        print('template:', url)

        # add requests to list
        for offset in range(0, num_reviews, 5):
            print('url:', url.format(offset))
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url.format(offset), callback=self.parse_reviews)

    def parse_reviews(self, response):
        print('reviews')
        for idx,review in enumerate(response.css('div.review-container')):
            item = {
                'num_reviews': response.css('span.reviews_header_count::text')[0].re(r'\d{0,3}\,?\d{1,3}'),
                'hotel_name': response.css('h1.heading_title::text').extract_first(),
                'review_title': review.css('span.noQuotes::text').extract_first(),
                'review_body': review.css('p.partial_entry::text').extract_first(),
                'review_date': review.xpath('//*[@class="ratingDate relativeDate"]/@title')[idx].extract(),
                'num_reviews_reviewer': review.css('span.badgetext::text').extract_first(),
                'reviewer_name': review.css('span.scrname::text').extract(),
                'bubble_rating': review.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'reviewItemInline')]//span[contains(@class, 'ui_bubble_rating')]/@class")[idx].re(r'(?<=ui_bubble_rating bubble_).+?(?=0)')
            }
            yield item


# --- run without project ---

import scrapy.crawler

c = scrapy.crawler.CrawlerProcess({
    "FEED_FORMAT": 'csv',
    "FEED_URI": 'output.csv',
})
c.crawl(TareviewsSpider)
c.start())
```

**BTW:** to get page you need url

```
 https://www.tripadvisor.com/g60795-d102542
 https://www.tripadvisor.com/g60795-d102542-or0
 https://www.tripadvisor.com/g60795-d102542-or5
```

Other words in url are only for `SEO` - to get better position in Google search results.